# Execute lua script after getting response from proxy pass

Tags: nginx

I have nginx block which proxy passes the request to different load balancers based on the request by first calling a lua script.

```
location / {
  set $provider_key null;
  set $cached_key null;
  set $credentials null;
  set $usage null;
  set $proxy_pass null;
  set $secret_token null;
  proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
  access_by_lua_file conf/3scale.lua;
  proxy_pass $proxy_pass ;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  Host  api.example.com;
  proxy_set_header X-3scale-proxy-secret-token $secret_token;
  post_action /out_of_band_authrep_action;
}
```

Now I have a requirement where for a particular api endpoint I need to capture a particular response header of the proxies request and call another lua script passing it the argument -  header value.

I am able to capture the value of that header in an nginx variable and able to print that log. What i didn't understand is where in the server block should i make the call this new lua script.

Hoping that someone will help me out.

Thanks !!

Comment: There is `header_filter_by_lua` directive.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri - did you figure out a way to do this? If so it would be great if you could share it here.

Comment: @DroidOS I also wasn't able to figure it out. Sorry.